# Aggregates in a subquery

Tags: sql

I'm fiddling around with creating sub queries just to become accustomed to them.  I'm trying to get an ID# and costs associated for a person if their ID appears in a junction table X number of times.  I've tried

```
select id, charges from myTable
where id in
(
    select id from jxnTable
having (count(jxn.id> 10))
group by jxn.id
```

This gives me the error `jxn.id is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function of a group by clause.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three errors:

- The GROUP BY and HAVING must be part of the same query, and the GROUP BY must come textually before the corresponding HAVING.
- The parentheses around your COUNT expression are incorrect.
- You have no table or alias called `jxn`.

Try this instead:

```
SELECT id, charges
FROM myTable
WHERE id IN
(
    SELECT id
    FROM jxnTable
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 10
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `GROUP BY` belongs inside the subquery, in addition to some odd `()` in your `HAVING` clause.

```
select id, charges from myTable
where id in
(
    select id from jxnTable
    GROUP BY id
    having (count(id>) 10)
)
```

This can also be done with a `JOIN` against a subquery, rather than an `IN()` clause, which may be faster:

```
SELECT m.id, charges
FROM myTable M
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT id FROM jxnTable
    GROUP BY id
    HAVING COUNT(id) > 10
  ) cnt  ON m.id = cnt.id
```

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry I edited your answer instead of mine: the page refreshed, and I clicked the wrong link.

Comment: I know this can be done with a join, but I'm trying to familiarize myself with sub queries :)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was in the process of editing when the edit notice popped up - my habit is to copy all my own edit so I can paste it back over the edit :)

Comment: @wootscootinboogie Both of them use a subquery - one is an `IN()` subquery and the other is a `JOIN` subquery.

Comment: @Michael I see now.  Are there any specific advantages for one way or the other?

Comment: @wootscootinboogie You need to examine the EXPLAIN output (query execution plan) for your query.  In some cases the subquery may get executed once per row returned, in which the join is lots faster.

Comment: For the time being optimization is outside of learning pay grade, but I want to keep it in mind as I learn.  Thanks!